# Storing locations in hierarchy - How to overcome?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

This is my schema for storing locations:

```
CREATE TABLE locality (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_1 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_2 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17)
);

CREATE TABLE administrative_area_level_3 (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17)
);

CREATE TABLE country (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
iso VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
loc VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (255)
);
```

Since they are a hieracy I want to link them together. For example:

```
USA ----> country(id=1) 
Washington ----> administrative_area_level3(id=54), country(id=1)
```

My issue is with this is that if I try to daisy chain the tables like this:

> locality -> administrative_area_level_1 -> administrative_area_level_2
>   -> administrative_area_level_3 etc

Then adding an entry like "Washington, USA" before adding "USA" will cause USA to be added. This is from a google geocode but that original geocode will only gives me the co-ordinate values of Washington and not that of "USA" generally. I would need to make a second geocoding request for USA and add these values separately.

My only option as far as I see is do something like this:

- See if Washington is in table already
- Geocode Washington
- Add results to administrative_area_level2 and country
- If country did not exist, geocode country and add "loc" coordinates

Is there a better or smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me say right up front that if you're working with hierarchies in a relational database, you *really* want this book:  [http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123877334)

Thinking about your Washington question, I'm wondering:  Are you unhappy because your table structure forces you to add an entry for "USA" when all you really want is "Washington?"

I'm not 100% I can answer your question, but let me tell you how I approach these types of problems.  I almost always model hierarchies in relational databases using paths.  Instead of 5 tables, I'd have one called "locations," which would look something like this:

```
create table locations (
    id varchar(10) not null primary key,
    path varchar(1000) not null unique,
    name varchar(40) not null,
    loc varchar(255) not null, -- from your model
    rad varchar(255) not null, -- from your model
);
```

"id" is a short identifier for each location, and "path" describes this location's position in the hierarchy in terms of its id and and ids of other locations.

So Washington would look like this:

```
id: wa
path: na/usa/wa
name: Washington
```

We're saying that Washington ("wa") is part of the USA ("usa") which is part of North America ("na").

Now at this point you can choose whether you want to actually include rows for "usa" and "na" or not.  You don't have to have rows for them in order to insert your "wa" row.  You could either insert the rows immediately, or never insert them (and just have your code understand that "wa" can be part of "usa" without "usa" being fully defined), or not insert them right away and have some job periodically run and add rows for any locations that appear in paths but don't have their own rows.

The Hierarchies book I reference above covers this path strategy in detail and includes lots of SQL code showing you how you can manipulate and browse the hierarchy.

Comment: You can use an array for the `path` in PostgreSQL, tends to work out much better than a delimited string. There's also WITH RECURSIVE which is quite handy for dealing with tree structures.